# Tessellation and Shaders with ARKit Face Geometry

Tags: swift, arkit, metal

Is it possible to use a tessellator with the ARKit Face Geometry, `ARSCNFaceGeometry`? I am curious to see if I can use a tessellator and shaders to manipulate the face geometry in different ways

Answer (score -2):

It appears that this does work, just not exactly in the way I thought it would